# Managing two main window MainWindow and threading

Tags: python, pyqt4

I updated somethings like calling the on_event method from the thread class and now i have this code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, pyodbc, serial
import os
import time
import thread
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

#Variables
Code_Zone = "d"

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, main):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.main = main
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.welcome = QtGui.QLabel("Bienvenue sur www.developpez.net", self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.welcome, 2, 2, 1, 5)

class AccessWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AccessWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 50)
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)

class Main(object):
    global EPC_Code
    def __init__(self):
        self.accueil = MainWindow(self)
        self.accueil.show()
        self.access = AccessWindow()

    def on_event(self, data):
        def refresh():
            self.toggle_widget(False)
            #c = AThread()
            c.run()
            #self.wait()
        # vérification des données 
        EPC_Code = data
        cnxn = """DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=Aziz-PC\SQLEXPRESS;PORT=1433;UID=poleindus;PWD=poleindus;DATABASE=indusdb"""
        db_connection = pyodbc.connect(cnxn)
        db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
        print ('Connected TO DB & READY')
        sql_command = "EXECUTE [Get_Access_RFID] @Code_RFID = '"+EPC_Code+"', @Code_Zone = '"+Code_Zone+"'"
        db_cursor.execute("EXECUTE [Get_Access_RFID] @Code_RFID = '"+EPC_Code+"', @Code_Zone = '"+Code_Zone+"'")
        rows = db_cursor.fetchone()
        result= str(rows[0])
        print ("result = " + str(result))
        if result == "True":
            # si OK
            self.access.label.setText('ACCESS GRANTED')
        else:
            # si pas OK
            self.access.label.setText('ACCESS DENIED')
        self.toggle_widget(True)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, refresh)

    def toggle_widget(self, b):
        self.accueil.setVisible(not b)
        self.access.setVisible(b)


class AThread(QtCore.QThread):
    rfid_event = pyqtSignal(str, name='rfid_event')

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200)
            a = ser.read(19).encode('hex')
            ser.close()

            if len(a) == 38:
                EPC_Code = a[14:]
                print ('EPC is : ' + EPC_Code)
                self.rfid_event.emit(EPC_Code)

if __name__=='__main__':
    #cnxn = """DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=Aziz-PC\SQLEXPRESS;PORT=1433;UID=poleindus;PWD=poleindus;DATABASE=indusdb"""
    #db_connection = pyodbc.connect(cnxn)
    #db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    #print ('Connected TO DB & READY')
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    thread = AThread()
    thread.rfid_event.connect(Main().on_event)
    thread.start()
    #main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have already added this line at the top of the code and now, i have another error:  The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.when i checked the value of the sql command, i find it equals to: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u"EXECUTE [Get_Access_RFID] @Code_RFID = 'e20010712904019411709bdd', @Code_Zone = 'd'")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new `Main` in `AThread`. That means you now have two of them (and worse, you create one every time you process an RFID event).

Also, you're not allowed to call methods from `Main` from inside a thread. Imagine what would happen if the thread would call them again before the first call would return: Data would be corrupted.

Instead, you must declare a signal in `AThread` and call `emit()` to send it. Your `Main` from the last block of code can then connect to this signal.

```
class AThread(QtCore.QThread):
    rfid_event = pyqtSignal(str, name='rfid_event')

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200)
            a = ser.read(19).encode('hex')
            ser.close()

            if len(a) == 38:
                EPC_Code = a[14:]
                print ('EPC is : ' + EPC_Code)
                self.rfid_event.emit(EPC_Code)
```

and later in the `__main__` code:

```
main = Main()
thread = AThread()
thread.rfid_event.coonect(Main.on_event)
thread.start()
#main = Main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also note that `thread.finished.connect(app.exit)` won't work: The thread contains an endless loop and never finishes. Instead, you should terminate the thread when the main window is closed.

I also fixed access to the serial port; you must close it every time.

Comment: thread.rfid_event.connect(Main.on_event)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__pyqtSignature__'

Comment: Add `from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal` at the top. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html explains how signals should be declared and used.

Comment: I have already added this line at the top of the code and now, i have another error: